# Placing SPFX ListViewExtension custom action into More expandable menu

Tags: custom-actions, spfx-extensions, listviewcommandset

I've created custom action as ListViewExtension and it works well, but i cannot figure out  how to  place it under expandable "More" menu.
My manifest.json is:

```
"unlock": {
      "pageUrl": "https://my/",
      "customActions": {
        "7b90c0ee-xxxx-4fbd-81cd-xxxxxxxxxx": {
          "location": "ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu",
          "properties": {
            
          }
        }
      }
```

Either i'm blind but i cannot see any hints in docs.

Answer (score 2):

The ListView Command Set extension does not enable you to specify the position of the command. See this question in the SharePoint Framework Issues list for more information [SPFX Change the position of a ListView Command Set button in the command bar](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/4204).

Note that the response from Pat Miller (patmill) includes links to User Voice. The SharePoint team is no longer using User Voice for feature requests so those links are no longer valid. The SharePoint team now uses the [Microsoft Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/), which includes this entry which, I think, relates to what you would like to do: [Support sub-menu options for List View Command Sets](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/4ae2016b-de1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8914). You can upvote it there.